# The same question is appearing multiple times in Ecosia search result

Tags: discussion, questions, search

I was doing this search with ecosia: [https://www.ecosia.org/search?tt=vivaldi&q=spring java anonymous bean](https://www.ecosia.org/search?tt=vivaldi&q=spring%20java%20anonymous%20bean) and the search result contains question [Anonymous Spring bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017019/anonymous-spring-bean) 3 times in the top 5:

> [image: ecosia search result]

There are different links presented for each ecosia search result:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017019/anonymous-spring-bean`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017019/anonymous-spring-bean?noredirect=1`
- `https://stackoverflow.com/a/4017100`

Is this a problem of SO?

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't appear to be a [`canonical` meta tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) on a question page, so this is something SO can probably improve.